# How do I use an encrypted MySQL password with Cyrus SASL?

Tags: linux, mysql, postfix, sasl

In /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf I have:

```
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_database: mail
sql_user: mailadmin
sql_passwd: secret
sql_select: SELECT password FROM users WHERE smtp_username = '%u'
sql_usessl: no
```

This is working if I place a plain text password in the `password` field, but the database uses passwords stored with the MySQL ENCRYPT() function. Since the Query selects the password, rather than using the password in the where clause, how do I check that the user supplied password when ENCRYPT()ed matches the encrypted password in the database?

Is it possible to change the query to use ENCRYPT()ed passwords?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/81958/postfix-sasl-mysql-use-md5-encryption